# Reflection.Emit and Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, reflection.emit

I'm trying to write dynamic method that calls Parallel.ForEach. I have checked a IL of a sample class and I noticed that there's a nested type generated that's named <>c__DisplayClass#

I did manage to create a dynamic implementation of Parallel.ForEach but my nested class is of normal type. It is not named as <>c__....

And I think because of that my generated code looks a bit different when inspecting it in Reflector:

```
private void SayHello(string name)
{
    SayHelloInvoker invoker = new SayHelloInvoker(name);
    Parallel.ForEach<ITest>(this, new Action<ITest>(invoker.SayHello));
}
```

But the compile code inspected in Reflector looks like:

```
private void SayHello(string name)
{
    Parallel.ForEach<ITest>(this, delegate (ITest x) { x.SayHello(name)); });
}
```

Current implementation works just fine but I would still like to figure out where's the catch in generating nested typed as <>c__....

So please if someone can point me in the right way so I can satisfy my curiosity. :)

Comment: on a whim, I'd say you should be using Expression trees with that framework version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make an anonymous method that uses variables from the parent method, the C# compiler generates a closure class named `<>c_...` to share those variables.

For more information, [see my blog post](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-4-c.html).

If you generate a method dynamically, you can do whatever you want to ensure that the method has access to the variables it needs.
In your case, your `SayHelloInvoker` is (presumably) serving the same role as the generated closure type, but with a more readable name, just like the `GreaterThan` class from my [previous closure-less example](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-3-c.html).